# spacebar won't make spaces in jquery-mobile text input types

Tags: jquery-mobile

Has anyone ever run into the problem of not neing able to type in spaces when using a text input type in jquery-mobile

Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0-beta.1/jquery.mobile-1.2.0-beta.1.min.css"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mobile-css.css"/>
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="dialog" data-theme="d">
    <div data-role="header" data-theme="d"><h5 style="margin: 0.6em 10% 0.5em;">Comment</h5></div>
    <div id="" data-role="content" data-theme="d">
        <label for="txtComment">Your Comment:</label>
        <input type="text" id="txtComment" data-theme="d">
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer" data-theme="d">
        <a href="#" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-transition="fade"
           class="cancelButton" data-theme="c" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
        <a href="#" data-role="button" id="btnSave" data-theme="d">Save</a>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sure thing, just added it, thats all there is for now.

Comment: Which browser are you using? Also, can you provide your HTML's header?

Comment: I'm getting this issue in the default web browser on android and iOS Safari.

Comment: What are the versions of your browsers? From your browser(s) you're using, can you input spaces in the online example at http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0-beta.1/docs/forms/textinputs/index.html ?

Comment: I'm not sure how to check that, but annoyingly enough I can type in spaces on that, so that definitely means its me implementation

Comment: I'll post a simple example, then you'll have a try :S. Please wait a sec

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple example (tested on iPhone 5), which uses the latest version of jQuery Mobile at the moment (1.2.0), and let me know if this works:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta name='viewport' content='minimum-scale=1.0, width=device-width, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no' />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile.structure-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>   

</head>

<body>

    <div data-role="page">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>HEADER</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <h1>my content</h1>
            <input type="text"/>
            <a data-role="button" href="#mydialog" data-rel="dialog">OPEN DIALOG</a>
        </div>

        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
            <h1>FOOTER</h1>
        </div>
    </div>

    <!-- YOUR DIALOG -->
    <div data-role="dialog" data-theme="d" id="mydialog">
        <div data-role="header" data-theme="d">
            <h5 style="margin: 0.6em 10% 0.5em;">Comment</h5>
        </div>
        <div id="" data-role="content" data-theme="d">
            <label for="txtComment">Your Comment:</label>
            <input type="text" id="txtComment" data-theme="d">
        </div>
        <div data-role="footer" data-theme="d">
            <a href="#" data-role="button" data-mini="true" data-inline="true" data-transition="fade"
                class="cancelButton" data-theme="c" data-rel="back">Cancel</a>
            <a href="#" data-role="button" id="btnSave" data-theme="d">Save</a>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
</html>
```

---

You should get the following:

[image: 1]

Try typing spaces in the input textbox:

[image: 2]

Then, click on the button `OPEN DIALOG`, which will lead you to your dialog box (the code you provided), and try inputting spaces inside the dialog's input textbox:

[image: 3]

I hope this will work for you. Anyway, let me know about your results mate.

Comment: I still seem to be having the spacebar problem, so very odd.